# Why is git review failing with 'failed to push refs' message?

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit

I've installed GitLab, and Gerrit and am currently testing out Gerrit using the Gerrit Wiki. However, whenever I try to push my change to gerrit using the gerrit_test branch, I'm getting this message when running git review -R. Any idea why this error is coming up?

```
$ git review -R
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/publish/master/gerrit_test': 'refs/publish/master' exists; cannot create 'refs/publish/master/gerrit_test'
To git@git.<host>.com:<user>/scripts.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master/gerrit_test (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.<host>.com:<user>/scripts.git
```

If there are any details I'm missing that may be helpful, let me know and I can share.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote has a branch foo, you can't push the foo/test branch because foo has been created as a file rather than a directory in the remote's refs directory.

Try creating a review of the non-master branch, perhaps feature/test-gerrit, or perhaps there is a setting for the pattern to use when creating a review branch from `git review`.

Comment: It seems that no matter what branch I create, it still uses 'refs/public/master/<insert new branch>'. Any particular reason why it's using public/master? Can I change this in any way?

Comment: According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Configuring_git-review you can tell it to use another remote other than "public" but unfortunately I don't know more about this at the moment. If you update your question hopefully someone will be able to help further.

Comment: That's also the same doc I've been following, unfortunately my results are different, even though my actions are the same.

Comment: http://docs.openstack.org/infra/git-review/installation.html appears to be there official documentation, as linked to from https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review - do you have a .gitreview file in your project?